# Error while finding an object in std::set

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to find an object inside the set using the find() method. However, I am unable to do that it seems I am sending a wrong key. What would be right way to do it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <utility>

struct Class {
  std::pair<int,int> data;
  int val = 0;
  int id = 0; ///ID for the object

};

struct CompClass {
      bool operator() (const Class& lhs, const Class& rhs) const
  {
    if (lhs.data.first == rhs.data.first) return lhs.data.second < rhs.data.second;

    return lhs.data.first<rhs.data.first;
    }
    };

int main ()
{

  Class c1,c2,c3,c4;


  c1.val = 92;c1.id = 2; c1.data = std::make_pair(92,2);
  c2.val = 94;c2.id = 3; c2.data = std::make_pair(94,3);
  c3.val = 92;c3.id = 1; c3.data = std::make_pair(10,1);

  std::set<Class,CompClass> fifth;                 // class as Compare

    fifth.insert(c1);fifth.insert(c2);fifth.insert(c3);

    for (auto x: fifth) {std::cout << x.id << "  " << x.val << std::endl;} 

    if (fifth.find(  std::make_pair(92,2)  ) != fifth.end() ) {std::cout << "Got it";} //Error

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?  the wrong result?

Comment: `std::pair<>` already has `operator<` defined exactly the way you used it, so just write `return lhs.data < rhs.data;`

Comment: @Slava : Noted (Thanks).

Comment: Why the downvote? The question is focused and contains a [mcve]. Better than quite a few other questions out there.

Comment: @Angew To be fair, that isn't a full MCVE: it doesn't contain what went wrong (in the above case, that it failed to build, and the error message resulting).

Comment: @Yakk Yes, there's some info missing from the *question* (and I could see people refraining from upvoting based on that, but a DV seems too much to me), but the MCVE itself is an actual MCVE, I would say. Anyway, I am fully aware that people are free to vote as they wish.

Comment: From the MCVE link: **Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::set<T>::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) takes an argument of type `T` in C++11. You need to provide a `Class` object, not a `std::pair`:

```
if (fifth.find(  Class{92,2,0,0}  ) != fifth.end() ) {std::cout << "Got it";}
```

Comment: In C++14 there is overload which takes anything, however you need to define comparison with other type and make comparator transparent.